# Which import type is the most suitable in case of a hierarchical data?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a directory tree (just a bunch of lines), which I transform in the following way:

```
/
/selinux
/run
/run/pppconfig
/run/sendmail
...
```

becomes

```
MERGE (r:Root {name: "", treeName: "tree"})
MERGE r<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_1:Node {name:"selinux"})
MERGE r<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_2:Node {name:"run"})
MERGE r<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_2)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_3:Node {name:"pppconfig"})
MERGE r<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_2)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_4:Node {name:"sendmail"})
...
```

But `/bin/neo4j-shell -path ~/dt -file ~/dirs.cypher` takes really long time for approximately 500K, which is not that big. Is there any alternative to this approach? Will transforming the source into CSV and loading with LOAD CSV show better result?

Upd.:

When CSV looks like this:

```
pid,nid,title
0,1,"a"
1,2,"b"
2,3,"c"
3,4,"d"
2,5,"e"
5,6,"f"
```

I am unable to create all the nodes at once because they seem to be inserted in a way that does not allow referencing a node that is to be inserted in this CSV file:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/dirs1.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (p:Node {nid: toInt(csvLine.pid)})
MERGE (p)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(c:Node {nid: toInt(csvLine.nid), title: csvLine.title})
```

So at first only `/a` is being inserted and `/a/b` is not, because `/a` is not present in the database at the beginning of the process. Can I somehow overcome this limitation in order to measure an execution speed of `LOAD CSV`?

Upd2.: So I decided to try another approach: first, do:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/roman/dirs1.csv' AS line
MERGE (c:Node {title: line[2], nid: toInt(line[1])})
```

and then I was going to run through the CSV again just to create relationships. But the nodes creation itself is incredibly slow! Something like ~1000 nodes/second! Now I'm writing the update and the first phase is still active. Am I doing something wrong? (Commit periods don't really matter, I tried 10K and the result is pretty much the same.)

And now for some updates if anyone is still interested in my problem.
First of all, I managed to achieve 10 second time for the first stage, i.e. just dumping nodes, by the means of creating not a constraint but just an index on the nodes' ids. But stage 2 (dumping the relationships) still takes 3-4 minutes, and that is quite an unacceptable amount of time. As for now, I'm going to play around with what I have, but in case you'll try something like I did - **do not create constraint prior to `LOAD CSV` if you have problems similar to mine. Dump time drastically decreases when you step back from constraints to indices.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, a significant improvement was made. First of all, I totally gave up on Cypher, but since the database had not to be stopped, I just used a single `Transaction` for a bunch of insertions. After some time spent varying transaction size, I found what suited best - something like 275 lines (i.e. 275 nodes + 275 relationships per single flush (`tx.success()`). But what helped me the most is caching nodes, so I won't need expensive db lookups. I used a trivial `Map<String, Node>`, where key was the full path to node and value was the node itself. So, having entry `<"", rootNode>` and path `/a`, we can easily create `Node{name : 'a'}` and its parent is `cache.get("") == rootNode` and so on. Now 500K dump takes ~55 seconds, and though that's still not even close to expected 5-15 seconds, it's something that works for us.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem and decided to try the [neo4j-shell](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#import-data-into-your-neo4j-database-from-the-neo4j-shell-command) way.

About performance, I get to insert 30k nodes in 6 secondes and 3M relationships in 1.5 minutes. This is not blazing fast but was quick enough for me.

The idea is to create CSV file for the nodes, `nodes.log`:

```
name:string|doc_id:string
lala|32189
lulu|38124
...
```

and import it in the `neo4j-shell` with a `CYPHER` query:

```
import-cypher -i path/to/nodes.log -d | -o path/to/batch.out -b 10000 CREATE (n {name: {name}, doc_id:{doc_id}}) SET n:Node RETURN id(n), n.name
```

Then, `batch.out` is transformed into a hashmap of `node id` used to access the nodes directly  in the `CYPHER` query that create the relationships. The idea is to skip the node lookup that is very costly.

```
import-cypher -i path/to/relationships.log -d | -b 100000  START n=node({start}), m=node({end}) CREATE (n)-[:IS_LIKE {property:{value}}]->(m)
```

with relationships.log:

```
start:int|end:int|value:float
1|2|4.56
1|4|1.23
...
```

The output of the commands show the performances, for the nodes:

```
finish after 32799 row(s)  3. 99%: nodes = 32799 rels = 0 properties = 163995 time 176 ms total 6449 ms
```

and for the relationships:

```
finish after 2925377 row(s)  29. 99%: nodes = 0 rels = 2925377 properties = 2925377 time 1433 ms total 100667 ms
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try, but up to now my best efforts with neo4j-shell (both cypher and csv approaches) result in ~3 minutes, that's sad.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multi-rel-paths for merge.

End each block of statements (e.g. per level) with a semicolon.

Don't forget to

```
create unique constraint on (n:Node) assert n.name is unique;
```

Or as this might not be the case, perhaps an index, but then you might have some incorrectly looked up paths. So probably better go with the pid, nid that you use later.

Then wrap 1k of them into a transaction with `begin` and `commit`

```
begin
MERGE (r:Root {name: "", treeName: "tree"})
MERGE r<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_1:Node {name:"selinux"})
MERGE r<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_2:Node {name:"run"});

MATCH (_2:Node {name:"run"})
MERGE (_2)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_3:Node {name:"pppconfig"})
MERGE (_2)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(_4:Node {name:"sendmail"})
commit
...
```

It spends a lot of time parsing that gigantic statement and then executing it in a single tx.

For quickly loading the CSV you can also use my CSV batch importer:

http://github.com/jexp/batch-import

When CSV looks like this:

```
pid,nid,title
0,1,"a"
1,2,"b"
2,3,"c"
3,4,"d"
2,5,"e"
5,6,"f"
```

You have to do merge on the nid too. And create the constraint for :Node.nid

```
create unique constraint on (n:Node) assert n.nid is unique; 

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/dirs1.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (p:Node {nid: toInt(csvLine.pid)})
MERGE (p)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(c:Node {nid: toInt(csvLine.nid)}) ON CREATE SET c.title=csvLine.title
```

Upd2.: So I decided to try another approach: first, do:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/roman/dirs1.csv' AS line
MERGE (c:Node {title: line[2], nid: toInt(line[1])})
```

Merge only works well on a single property as it can use a constraint or index then.

Something else you can try is to split your CSV up into chunks of 100k.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/roman/dirs1.csv' AS line
WITH line
SKIP 200000 LIMIT 100000
MERGE (c:Node {nid: toInt(line[1])}) ON CREATE SET c.title=line[2]
```

**Update:**

Unfortunately you run into one cypher issue with LOAD CSV :( Can you try to split your input file into smaller sizes like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/roman/dirs1.csv' AS line
WITH line
SKIP 40000 limit 20000
MATCH 
  (parent:Node {nid: toInt(line[0])}), 
  (child: Node {nid: toInt(line[1])})
CREATE
  (child)-[:CHILD_OF]->(parent)
```

Comment: Yes, I did create the constraints on `nid`s, but the main reason it's slow is not the node creation (I managed to insert 500K nodes (`nid`+`title`) in 10 seconds). The relationships are the reason it takes so long. I do something like this: https://gist.github.com/cdshines/1bb883e8c161319ed86e and it takes 10-15 minutes to import (on my SSD!), even with unique constraint on `nid`. Do I insert relationships in a most efficient way or is there something better I could do?

Comment: I tried processing nodes in smaller chunks (like this: https://gist.github.com/cdshines/aad74c888950b4478bfa), but it seems that nothing's gonna help me in this particular case. Anyway, thank you for your advise.